# Wordpress hide category from url structure

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, mod-rewrite

I have url structure like this

```
http://www.domain.dom/blog/%category%/%postname%/
```

and in theme functions.php following rule

```
function wpa58471_category_base() {
// Remember to flush the rules once manually after you added this code!
add_rewrite_rule(
    // The regex to match the incoming URL
    'blog/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)(/[0-9]+)?/?$',
    // The resulting internal URL
    'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]/$matches[2]&name=$matches[3]&paged=$matches[4]',
    // Add the rule to the top of the rewrite list
    'top' );
}
```

Code found on this site

So now url in browser look's like this:
     `http://www.domain.dom/blog/cars/new-car-on-market/`

Problem:

When users want to browse all posts in cars category the url is :

```
http://www.domain.dom/blog/category/cars/
```

I want to hide /category/ part. Is it possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try [Remove Category URL](https://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-category-url/) plugin.

OR

Follow this blog [How To Remove Category From Your URLs In WordPress](https://jonnyjordan.com/blog/how-to-remove-category-from-your-urls-in-wordpress/)

Comment: I allready have Yoast SEO plugin so this was easy fix. Thanks

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).